# Remove default Site Templates in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am working with `Liferay 6.1`. The default Liferay comes with 2 `Site Templates` (Community Site Template, Intranet Site).

Is there any way to have a default Liferay instance without these Site Templates? That means, if I start Liferay, it should not install/add these Site Templates.

Few updates

- I checked `portal.properties`, did not find any property to control this.
- I checked the `portal-data-sample.vm` and `portal-data-*.sql` files, did not find any entry in `LayoutSetPrototype` table.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the initial DB scripts are setting these Templates. For example, if you try opening a clean Liferay portal, in /data/hsql/lportal.script, you can see that the initail portal will have these values , eg.:

```
INSERT INTO LAYOUT VALUES(NULL,27,23,1,NULL,NULL,'1',1,0,'<?xml version="1.0"?>\u000a\u000a<root>\u000a  <name>Liferay, Inc. Intranet</name>\u000a</root>',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'portlet','layout-template-id=2_columns_ii\u000acolumn-1=3,\u000acolumn-2=19,','0','/1',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

or

```
INSERT INTO LISTTYPE VALUES(10012,'intranet','com.liferay.portal.model.Account.website')
```

INSERT INTO LISTTYPE VALUES(10013,'public','com.liferay.portal.model.Account.website')

INSERT INTO LISTTYPE VALUES(12019,'intranet','com.liferay.portal.model.Organization.website')
INSERT INTO LISTTYPE VALUES(12020,'public','com.liferay.portal.model.Organization.website')

I think that your best bet is to alter the Liferay portal, and bundle it for your next installations, something like:

1. install the portal
2. set up with the absolut minimum configs, and set your Templates
3. export your database
4. shutdown your server
5. replace the initial db scripts with your script
6. delete the portal-setup-wizard.properties and portal-ext.properties, so after each time you deploy your site, the setup will run again
7. compress your Liferay Folder from the parent folder of 'data' and keep it as a starting bundle for your next projects

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I checked the initial DB scripts but the thing is that there is no entry for the LayoutSetPrototype (table which stores site templates info).

Comment: I think that the creation and installation of these Layouts is a combination of info in 'data' folder, and the Liferay database. This is the reason I believe that bundling up this info in a fresh Portal

Comment: I found the answer, added the same.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the place. Liferay has the new set of events. One of them is `AddDefaultDataAction`. This calls one more action called `AddDefaultLayoutPrototypesAction`. In this class, the liferay creates default site templates.